# Did a worker thread in blocking state used to yield and return to the threadpool in the old threadpool model before TAP/TPL?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, threadpool

Please correct my understanding.

Before the Task-based Asynchronous Programming model was introduced, the .NET ThreadPool worked differently.

1) Under the old system, when a thread was blocking on a I/O completion port, did it yield its slice of the CPU time to the OS while it was in blocking state?

2) Is my understanding correct that after the new thread pool and task scheduler implementation that came with TPL, that now a thread returns to the thread-pool immediately after entering the blocking state?

3) And that in the old regime, the blocked thread did not go back to the thread-pool and hence caused unnecessary overhead of thread injection that could have been avoided?

Comment: No, neither the ThreadPool implementation nor the scheduler were changed.  And ThreadPool.SetMin/MaxThreads() always took an *completionPortThreads*
argument.  And TPL does not occupy a thread while I/O is in progress.  TAP just made the callback method a lot easier to write, the C# compiler now writes it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the bulk of my question is: earlier, when a thread pool thread was in blocking state, could it have been used for something else? If it returned to the pool then, too, it could have been off-loaded its execution context to some place else and been used for something else. Then what real cost did TPL save? If, however, it could not be used for something else while blocked, there's a real benefit to the *task* abstraction and not having the user to think about thread as a unit of work, so now any thread could steal work from others?

Comment: A few lectures in Operating Systems Architecture and some reading of Managed Threading from the MSDN has revealed to me my own imbecility in asking this inane, uneducated question, and for having the hubris (it wasn't hubris as much as it was blind ignorance) to talk back with @HansPassant, who is like the Guy de Maupassant of low-level programming. I stand afar, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Under the old system, when a thread was blocking on a I/O
>   completion port, did it yield its slice of the CPU time to the OS
>   while it was in blocking state?

Yes. It WILL basically call the await equivalent on the completion port. Note the "WILL". NOTHING has changed in this regard.

> 2) Is my understanding correct that after the new thread pool and task
>   scheduler implementation that came with TPL,

Nothing new came here at all. Where do you get the delusion from? TPL is built on top of the tread pool. It did neither change it, nor magically rewrite the KERNEL LEVEL SCHEDULER.

> 3) And that in the old regime, the blocked thread did not go back to the 
>   thread-pool and hence caused unnecessary overhead of thread injection that 
>   could have been avoided?

It still is like this. You are still free to use the standard API. Anything else is built on top with some compiler tricks to make calling the API easier, but nothing has changed. There are still cases where the old API is better.

So, that part is wrong. The rest is right - a thread is not usable from the pool until it is returned there. And the standard threading API does not return. The new one does neither - the thread is returned to the task scheduler which uses it on another task, but from the thread pool side nothing has changed.

Comment: Thank you. I heard Jeffrey Richter (I think) say on one of the Channel 9 videos that with .NET 4.5, they were re-writing the `ThreadPool` class implementation. But I was alluding to the new features of *work stealing / load balancing* and such that didn't exist before but I see what you're saying. It uses the same old infrastructure.

Comment: No. They did some reworkgon the thread pool to make it more efficient. For example threads are now shared between appdomains. But the stealing etc. are not done in the thread pool. The TaskScheduler sits on top of normal threads and allocates them to the tasks. At the end of the day, Threads are a kernel level mechanism (at least in the Windows implementation).

Comment: Yes, of course, work stealing is done by the scheduler and the thread pool still only either queues work items or managed min and max threads in it and anticipates and deals with over-subscription. I did not infer that the thread pool does that. I just thought that they had re-written the thread pool also, which you have clarified. And as you say, re-write / refactor of the thread pool to sit in the new paradigm would have been inevitable. I just thought that the ThreadPool behaved drastically differently now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It turns out I was clearly misled by my own incomprehension. It wasn't Jeffrey Richter but Joe Duffy instead in this interview (https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Programming-in-the-Age-of-Concurrency-Anders-Hejlsberg-and-Joe-Duffy-Concurrent-Programming-with) where Charles interviews Anders Hejlsberg and Joe Duffy about TPL, PFX and PLINQ. What Joe said between 11:55 (https://youtu.be/cyAVClrZUO0?t=715) and 13:18 (https://youtu.be/cyAVClrZUO0?t=800) was the reason for my confusion, which, in hindsight I realize he was saying exactly the opposite of what I thought he was saying.